# What is the formal grammar equivalent to this regex?

Tags: regex

The regular expression is (a+)+ . Using an NFA this would give [reDOS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) for longer strings .  What would be the equivalent grammar for this regular expression ?

Now i was trying to determine the grammar in multiple steps .

a+ would translate to

```
S -> a
S -> aS
```

(a+)+ would translate to

```
G -> S
G -> SG
```

I was not sure how to simplify further whether it would be CFG or CSG  ? Any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a+)+` is equivalent to `a+`. A possible grammar is

- S → A
- A → a
- A → aA

The grammar is regular (such one must exist, because it's derived from a regular expression). It's therefore also context-free and therefore also context-sensitive.

Comment: does this mean any regular expression would result in regular grammar ?

Comment: Yes. Regular expressions, regular grammars and finite automata are equivalent.

Comment: I guess you are talking about "pure" regular expressions but not the ones as in PCRE . http://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html